# Not getting the css and js effect on view page in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel-5

i have created a small nav bar which i downloaded from a website. i have pasted the html in welcome.blade.php and i have put the css in public folder

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/styles.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <title>CSS MenuMaker</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Products</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Company</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
<html>
```

this is my css code

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #47c9af;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > a {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 18px 25px 12px 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444444;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
  -moz-transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
  -moz-transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover:after {
  background: #47c9af;
}
```

but when i run the page the page doesn't show any effect,just a white page menu listed in normal font.
i know it is a simple thing but as am new to laravel please help me

Comment: Please provide enough details to figure it out like laravel version and are you using any tools like elixir

Comment: am using laravel latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use laravel's `asset()` helper for js and css files and it's better to include your scripts after body tag. Try this:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang=''>
    <head>
       <meta charset='utf-8'>
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/styles.css')}}">
       <title>CSS MenuMaker</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
       <li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
       <li><a href='#'>Products</a></li>
       <li><a href='#'>Company</a></li>
       <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="{{asset('js/script.js')}}"></script>
    <html>
```